# Testing Cross-site authentication with Visual Studio

Tags: forms-authentication

Is it possible to add to websites to a VS solution and test cross-site forms-authentication?

I'd imagine this would simulate the same behavior between www.site.com and subdomain.site.com.

Am I correct?

Are there articles out there explaining how to do this (yes, I did search first ;-) )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, I've found this very difficult using the default ASP.NET Development Server (a.k.a. Cassini. Yes, they're the same...), mainly because the applications/web sites were running on different ports and had trouble communicating. The two trivial options are to either

a) set the port manually in each project's properties, so they all run on the same one

or

b) debug in IIS instead (which is also set in the project properties), and then get everything done on the default port 80.

I did the latter, and it worked for me.

Comment: This will only work on a version of IIS that permits multiple sites.

Comment: I haven't tried b) with the different sites as Virtual Directories (which is supported on IIS 5.1 and 6 also), and I don't know if they would even qualify as different applications (thus making SSO testing impossible...). a), however, works even if you don't have IIS at all.